# max_usb_current uneffective?

Tags: power-supply, usb-power

I found out that my raspberry freezes when having connected Huawei E3131 USB dongle... and the signal is really low. At first I thought that it may be connected to max current from USB... as specs say that they use at peek 700mA. But max_usb_current is on, and it doesn't change a thing... what could be wrong? Why does it freeze? When dongle is disconnected, it doesn't freeze.

2.4A good quality power supply.

Comment: What Pi model are you using? What voltage do you see between pins 2 (5V) and 6 (ground)?

Comment: ~5V, Raspberry Pi 2

Comment: Checking out `dmesg` once you plug the dongle might shed some light on the issue. I wouldn't be surprised if they violated the 700mA limit, GSM stuff is often quite power-hungry.